# completed and async methods in windows phone 7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a problem with using completed and async methods in windows phone 7 application.

My code is here:

```
private void messageClient_getMessageOfUserCompleted(object sender, ADRTRYST_CLIENT.LocalHostMessageService.getMessageOfUserCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //lstBxMessages.ItemsSource = e.Result;

        System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<ADRTRYST_CLIENT.LocalHostMessageService.OBJMessage> mesList = e.Result;
        foreach (ADRTRYST_CLIENT.LocalHostMessageService.OBJMessage mes in mesList)
        {
            MessageObj message = new MessageObj();
            message.Date = mes.MessageDate;
            messageList.Add(message);
            ADRTRYST_CLIENT.LocalHostMemberShipService.MemberShipSoapClient memClient = new ADRTRYST_CLIENT.LocalHostMemberShipService.MemberShipSoapClient();
            MessageBox.Show(memClient.State.ToString());
            memClient.GetUserByUserIdCompleted += new EventHandler<ADRTRYST_CLIENT.LocalHostMemberShipService.GetUserByUserIdCompletedEventArgs>(memClient_GetUserByUserIdCompleted);  
            memClient.GetUserByUserIdAsync(mes.SenderUserID);

            lstBxMessages.Items.Add(mes.MessageDate);

        }
    }


    private void memClient_GetUserByUserIdCompleted(object sender, ADRTRYST_CLIENT.LocalHostMemberShipService.GetUserByUserIdCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        ADRTRYST_CLIENT.LocalHostMemberShipService.OBJPerson user = e.Result;
        if (user != null)
            lstBxMessages.Items.Add(user.UserName);

    }
```

I have expected that seeing a date of message then the sender of message in the listbox.
However, firstly all dates are listed and then sender names are listed int the listbox.
How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Because the events are firing asynchronously, the ListBox is being filled with all the `MessageDates` in the `foreach` loop first. If the `MessageDate` is not part of the completed event arguments, then you could use an anonymous method for the completed event to fill the list box with the `MessageDate` and `User`:

```
memClient.GetUserByUserIdCompleted += (obj, e) => 
{
    if (e.Result == null)
        return;

    lstBxMessages.Items.Add(mes.MessageDate);
    lstBxMessages.Items.Add(e.Result.UserName);
}
memClient.GetUserByUserIdAsync(mes.SenderUserID);
```

Comment: that does not work. timeout exception is unhandled in GetUserByUserId method.